# Changing the `input-field` color in MaterializeCSS

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I am making a personal website for personal use, using [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) as a design template.

I was wondering if I could change the green-ish color on an input field like this

[image: Like this]

to another color, like red.

I have two input fields, a Username field, and a password field, with the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12" action="?p=SignIn" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input id="UserName" type="text" class="validate white-text" name="UserName">
          <label for="UserName">Username</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s3">
          <input id="Password" type="password" class="validate white-text" name="Password">
          <label for="Password">Password</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and as stated before, I'm using [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

The color is displayed by CSS (or in this case written in SASS).

I looked this file up: materialize/sass/components/forms/_input-fields.scss
There we have the variable: $input-focus-color

You can change the input colors and other variables in the file:
materialize/sass/components/_variables.scss

Then compile it back to css.
Thats it.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try the below css,

```
input, input:focus { 
    background-color: black;
}

label{
    color: red;
}
```